# Error 404 cant find javascript file in folder on cloud 9 using node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cloud9

I am building a website and  i am using node.js on cloud9 platform. I want to use jquery to make a weather API request. So i created a file with a name weather.js and stored my code in it. But when i run the web page i get an error: GET https://my-restfull-web-app-billias86.c9users.io/weather.js 404 (Not Found).
When i transfered my jquery code to footer.ejs file, the code runs without errors. I searched the web but i couldn't find a solution. I found that the problem is the program can't read my weather.js file. I tried: app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public")); but it din't work. I don't know what to do.
My construction folder is:
[forlder construction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwMCM.jpg)

**A part of my server code in my app.js  is:**

```
var bodyParser   = require("body-parser"),
methodOverride   = require("method-override"),
expressSanitizer = require("express-sanitizer"),
mongoose         = require("mongoose"),
express          = require("express"),
rpromise         = require('request-promise'),
request          = require("request"),
//serveStatic      = require('serve-static'),
app              = express();


//console.log(process.env.DATABASEURL);

//App Config
var url = process.env.DATABASEURL || "mongodb://localhost/restfull_web_app";
mongoose.connect(url, {useMongoClient: true});
//mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASEURL, {useMongoClient: true});
//mongoose.connect("mongodb://Billy:billias@ds127126.mlab.com:27126/movieblog", {useMongoClient: true});

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extented: true}));
app.use(expressSanitizer());
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function() {
    console.log("The Web App Server has started!");
});


//app.use(express.static("public"));
//app.use('weather', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

**This is the footer.ejs code:**

```
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="scripts/weather.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

**And this is the index.ejs where i will display the results from the API request:**

```
 <% include ./partials/header %>

<div class = "ui main text container">
   <div class="main">
        <h2 id="currentLoc">
            Getting location...<span id="nameLoc"></span><!-- This is where the weather forecast will be shown for now-->
        </h2>
        <p id="weather"></p>
        <p id="temp"></p>
        <p id="highLow"></p>
        <a id="toggle" href="#">Toggle &#8451; / &#8457;</a>

    </div>

    <div class="ui huge header">Movie Blog</div>
        <div class="ui top attached segment"><!-- This gives a line box -->
            <div class="ui divided items">
                <% movies.forEach(function(movie) { %>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="<%= movie.image %>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <a class="header" href="/movies/<%= movie._id %>"><%= movie.title%></a>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <span><%= movie.created.toDateString() %></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="description">
                                <p><%= movie.body.substring(0, 100) %>...</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="extra">
                                <a class="ui floated basic  violet button"  href="/movies/<%= movie._id %>">
                                    Read More
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <% }) %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, i found the mistake. My file was in the wrong directory. Now it's working fine.